# ShrinkToFit cause header shifting

Tags: jqgrid

When I set shrinkToFit to true, everything is ok with data rows but there are some problems with header columns like in a picture. Their with is not correct. Can someone help me to solve this?
[image]

Comment: `shrinkToFit: true` is **default** option of jqGrid. So setting `shrinkToFit: true` should change nothing. If you have some problem you should post JavaScript code of jqGrid and probably test JSON data which can be used to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

`autoWidth:true`

But note that jqGrid get width from parent node,so there can be issues if you use `float:`

Answer (score 1):

Steps to reproduce this issue in my case:

1) Setup grid with

```
shrinkToFit: true;
```

2) Call

```
.jqGrid('setGroupHeaders' ...)
```

3) Change grid width by

```
setGridWidth()
```

and you have shifted headers